# Help me find a font that looks something like this...

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Ok, this is a horrible drawing I know but looking for font recommendations that might get me close. Basically I am looking for a font that uses 3 stripes to create connecting letters. The letters in this (horrible) drawing are CFR. Any ideas what would get me close?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While the style you're trying to get across will ultimately need some manual vector manipulation, here are some typefaces to get you started:

[image]

Comment: Judging by the style of the font names (and the +web badge) it seems all can be found from [myfonts.com](http://myfonts.com) Also while you're at it, check the fonts [tagged "multi-line"](http://new.myfonts.com/search/tag%3Amulti-line/fonts/) from the same site for more alternatives.

Comment: Did you happen to know these fonts or did you use a font website to search for a font based on a style. If the latter, I'd be interested to know how you went about finding these fonts based on some visual characteristics, as you've got some close matches here! [EDIT @koiyu - you read my mind and beat me to it! thank you]

Comment: @Roger, I looked the fonts up on myfonts.com, just like koiyu said. The fonts I listed are primarily from these two tags: http://new.myfonts.com/search/tag%3Aneon/fonts/ and http://new.myfonts.com/search/tag%3A%22op+art%22/fonts/

Answer (score 1):

For any similar future quest(ion)s, you can let this site http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ recognise most fonts. Really useful tool for any designer and typographer.

Comment: Good advice, but it's already listed in the tag wiki: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Comment: ok I didn't know there was such a thing :)

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)